# How to Loop a Multi-dimensional Array (3D)?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Given the following array:

```
content =   [
number1 =   [
            ["link1",   "text1"],
            ["link2",   "text2"],
            ["linkN",   "textN"]
            ],

number2 =   [
            ["link1",   "text1"],
            ["link2",   "text2"],
            ["linkN",   "textN"]
            ],

numberN =   [
            ["link1",   "text1"],
            ["link2",   "text2"],
            ["linkN",   "textN"]
            ]
            ];
```

Using a "for loop", how do I get this output:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="slide">link1-text1, link2-text2, linkN-textN</div> //from number1
 <div class="slide">link1-text1, link2-text2, linkN-textN</div> //from number2
 <div class="slide">link1-text1, link2-text2, linkN-textN</div> //from numberN
</div>
```

Do I need to nest the "for loop"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think firstly you can minimize the 3d array into a 1D array like the code below for making it easy. What it does converts an item to `link1-text1, link2-text2, linkN-textN` format.

```
const newContent = content.map(items => {
   return items.map(item => item.join('-')).join(', ');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. No need to name the arrays though

```js
content = [
  [
    ["link1", "text1"],
    ["link2", "text2"],
    ["linkN", "textN"]
  ],

  [
    ["link1", "text1"],
    ["link2", "text2"],
    ["linkN", "textN"]
  ],

  [
    ["link1", "text1"],
    ["link2", "text2"],
    ["linkN", "textN"]
  ]
];


document.querySelector(".wrapper").innerHTML = content.map(arr =>
  `<div class="slide">${arr.map(item => item.join("-")).join(", ")}</div>`
).join("\n")
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```